# Cannot create Database entry onClick using Prisma and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, database, next.js, prisma, supabase

I have a Next.js local project I am working on that uses a Supabase PostgreSQL database and Prisma. I have a button on my page that I would like to click and then create a new database entry. This is my code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function uploadToDB(){
    
    const user = await prisma.tableName.create({ data: {name:"Random Name"}})

}

export default function Home() {

 return(
   <div>
    <button onClick={e => uploadToDB()}></button>
   </div>
 )
}
```

The create to the database works fine when not attached to the button onClick event. Is there anyway to accomplish this? The error I receive is:

*- error Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.*

```
<button className=... onClick={function} children=...>
```

*If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component at stringify*

I have attempted adding in 'use client' at the top of the page however I then receive the error:

*Error: PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser*

Any help on fixing this error or a complete workaround would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Next 13, all the components are Server Components by default, if you want interactivity you need to add `use client` directive at the top, refer [here.](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components)

I see that after you've added the `use client` directive, it threw the error that Prisma cannot run in the browser, you can read more about that error [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6219).

To fix this issue, remove the `use client` directive and use [Next.js Route Handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers) to build a route that creates the table using Prisma and then call that API route in the client component, here's a nice guide for that [Prisma with Next 13](https://codevoweb.com/how-to-setup-prisma-orm-in-nextjs-13-app-directory/)